# how to get more number variance compared as the csv output file of two model stl files in Cloudcompare

Tags: modeling

we are using the [CloudCompare](https://www.danielgm.net/cc/) for comparing two mouth STL model for Final doctoral theses, like works done in [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/319698918_Mandibular_Surgical_Navigation_An_Innovative_Guiding_Method)([pdf](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Vincenzo_Abbate3/publication/319698918_Mandibular_Surgical_Navigation_An_Innovative_Guiding_Method/links/59fb57d20f7e9b9968b9bff5/Mandibular-Surgical-Navigation-An-Innovative-Guiding-Method.pdf?_sg%5B0%5D=mHsXK3vdmqqMtk8QEsoozmteG5F8kJewDn-ZcM0rcMzenPXOG1xt0q3mvLQvdk5ifFOwlahUnDnTeMHj90E68g.rfPtUCDRIU_NM2xQps_mlq_CmuSzua12c2_q-3HkvEeImgguvUIf-n6ps28cDFpk4r5E9VFnJHDtZetPcBHIAQ&_sg%5B1%5D=8sFiJcM7BsFO_hnehQ2W48wiyfwA2B8UFMZivaW1F7Z-YSaoLb3HS4GOCZsTeoIKXyt2QqsLg4WQa7Hz3lgjU3-7D-T8P__Vy--dR3CvaDBa.rfPtUCDRIU_NM2xQps_mlq_CmuSzua12c2_q-3HkvEeImgguvUIf-n6ps28cDFpk4r5E9VFnJHDtZetPcBHIAQ&_iepl=)) shown blow:

[image]

and the instruction said [here](https://www.cloudcompare.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=3452):

[image]

so i have tried to insert the STL file and use this align method :

[image]

so the output are only 256 numbers by this columns names:

[image]

so asked how to increase the result number of compared output result in CSV file and is this methods is right for accessing to the compared this two models?

also what is the means of the csv colums means whis are like this:

[image]

i have uploaded the two STL files here, for more information.

http://s7.picofile.com/file/8387291350/stl_files.zip.html

Thanks for your attention.